# Can I force sqlsrv_connect (PHP) to use windows authentication with supplied credentials?

Tags: php, sql-server, active-directory, sqlsrv

Setup: intranet SQL Server and Domain Controller. In the DMZ we have a web server (IIS, PHP7).

SQL Server has mixed mode authentication. I'm trying to migrate from an old API setup (PHP5, mssql_connect), to a new setup (PHP7, IIS).

With the old API setup, authentication happens through mssql_connect using the supplied username and password, and connects to the sql server without a problem. The username and password are DOMAIN credentials, and setup on SQL SERVER as GROUPS. This makes it much easier to add/remove users, and works very well.

New API setup attempt #1:
 - sqlsrv_connect: Supplying username and password forces sqlsrv_connect to use SQL USER authentication instead of WINDOWS authentication. Because the users are on the domain but NOT assigned directly to the SQL SERVER, this fails.

attempt #2:
 - sqlsrv_connect: not supplying username and password forces sqlsrv_connect to connect via windows authentication with set credentials (not what we need). Yes, we could set these credentials to whatever we want, but then any stored procedures within SQL SERVER which check usernames might return our 'set user', rather than the actual client username.

attempt #3:
 - PDO:sqlsrv: - Same thing with and without usernames.

attempt #4:
 - do LDAP authentication (with credentials) then sqlsrv_connect (without credentials). This allows me to verify the user should have access to the database, but does not allow me to see the username from within stored procedures.

I've read MANY posts on this topic from google, stackoverflow, and other places. NONE of them address having an API hosted in a DMZ where YOU DON'T WANT the WEBSERVER ITSELF to have credentials that can access the database. What we need is for the USER SUPPLIED credentials to be passed through the API (web server) and into the SQL server as "Windows Authentication" (not as SQL Users). That way any queries to the SQL server are performed as THE USER, and we can manage the users via the directory.

Most of the posts infer that the users gave up and went with SQL USER authentication (sounds like a management headache), or enabled anonymous access from the webserver to SQL server (also seems like a bad idea with the webserver in the DMZ).

Am I completely off my rocker to expect this to work? I know this is not a standard SO question, but I'm not sure where else to put this. If you know of any posts/pages where the above is done (using explicit credentials to connect with Windows Authentication with sqlsrv), please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done with [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553400(v=ws.11).aspx).

That requires your web site to use Windows Authentication (Kerberos, not NTLM), and your web site would not have any access to the user's credentials.  How and if that works in PHP, I don't know.  But there's lots of info on how to set it up and do it in ASP.NET.  Basically IIS has a token you can use to Impersonate.

If you are accepting credentials over Forms or Basic auth and want to use those to connect to SQL Server using Windows Auth, you can't just paste them into the connection string.  You have to change the security context of the thread using Impersonation.

First you use the credentials to perform an actual logon with the [LoginUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) API.  Then you use the returned handle to [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx).  After with you can connect to SQL Server with Windows integrated auth.  At the end of the request you would call [RevertToSelf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317(v=vs.85).aspx) to stop running as the requesting end user.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But the problem is that the credentials (username & password) ARE being sent from the mobile client into the PHP API, but there is no way to make use of them within the PHP API to connect to the SQL server. Note that this works with php_mssql prior to 5.6, with the API running on a linux host.

Comment: "but there is no way to make use of them within the PHP API to connect to the SQL server"  AFAIK you would have to perform a Login and change the impersonate on the thread while connecting to SQL Server.  I doubt that actually works on Linux either as it would have to use Kerberos.